# Удаление части html страницы в WebBrowser WPF

Tags: c#, html, wpf, dom, webbrowser

Добрый день!

**Вопрос:** подскажите, как удалить часть страницы, которая открыта в компоненте WebBrowser, и отобразить ее?

Так понимаю нужно спарсить страницу и занести ее в dom-дерево?

Много примеров как это сделать в windows forms, но по Wpf найти не могу. 
Cпасибо)

Comment: Вы могли бы просто использовать WebBrowser из WindowsForms через WindowsFormHosted. Иначе с WPF WebBrowser  замучаетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось прикрутить браузер Windows Forms, тогда:

```
  dynamic htmldoc = Browser.Document.DomDocument;
        dynamic Header = htmldoc.GetElementById("тэг");
        if (Header != null)
        {
            Header.parentNode.removeChild(globalHeader);
        }
```

Comment: Можно еще и так  Browser.Document.GetElementById("idElementRemoved").OuterHtml = "";

Comment: спасибо за совет)